# keychain stored password is still available after app re-installed

Tags: ios, keychain

I am developing iOS app with xcode8+swift3.

I have created functions to store user password to keychain and read password out from keychain. You can refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45617160/successfully-stored-string-value-to-keychian-but-always-failed-to-read-it-out) for the functions I have created.

The problem I noticed in general is, even I uninstalled the app, when I re-install the app, my app read password from keychain is the old password from previously installed app (which has uninstalled already).

My question is, what is the best practice to address this issue?

Comment: items store in keychain persists even you delete the app. If you don't want the old details, you can delete the keychain items after you install the app

Comment: Yes, I would think the same, but where is the best place to do that in practice? AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions ?

Comment: u can store a bool flag in userdefaults, and check in AppDelegate. USerdefualts gets deleted when you delete the app, so that should work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the app delegate you can do:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

   BOOL savedInKeychain = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"savedInKeychain"];
   if(!savedInKeychain){
    //There is no keychian data saved in this app
    //check if data exisst in keychain
    if(kechainData){
        //Delete keychain data
    }

   return YES;
}
```

Later after you save data in keychain, set savedInKeychain to YES in userdefaults.

Answer (score 0):

Keychain is encrypted and persistent after uninstallation.
NSUserdefaults aren't encrypted (not recommended to store password) and aren't persistent after uninstallation.

To check if is the first launch of the app and reset keychain you can use this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
    if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"])
    {
        // reset keychain
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
    return YES;
}
```